# Adding a String in front of/right after a match via 'sed'

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed

I have a bunch of files with Strings I want to search for a specific match: "**exampledata**"

Looks like this:

```
...(...name: Example; age: 21; version: 2131; exampledata: hello;) end
```

**if** in a line the "exampledata" **is defined** then **do nothing**, otherwise **add** that string exampledata with lets say a number right after the version number (which could be 1 cipher or up to 5-6) OR put it right before the closing bracket "**)**" which is always the pattern in the Strings. (i.e. "Exampledata" is right after version and at the end of the Strings. Only a "**)**" comes after it.)

```
sed '/exampledata:"/b; /\version.....;\/s/&"exampledata: 2"/'
```

this is what i worked out so far, i dont know how to make the dots after version interactive bc. in every line there could be a single cipher version or a higher number. ideas?

Basically im looking for a sed command that adds an "exampledata: 2;" if there was no exampledata at all before for instance? (result would be like this: **blabla...(...version: 98; exampledata: 2;)**

Comment: Use `!/pattern/command` to execute the command on any line that doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: The command should replace `)` with `exampledata: 2;)`

Comment: thanks @Barmar edited the question to what ive already been working out. the idea with replacing ) with exampledata: 2;) is great! gonna work with that

Comment: There are no double quotes around `version: 2131`, why do you have them in the pattern?

Comment: Is `metadata:` supposed to be `exampledata:`?

Comment: thought they were necessary. yes youre correct on the meta/example issue. corrected both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patterns have double quotes that don't appear in the data.

```
sed '/exampledata:/!s/version: [0-9]*;/& exampledata: 2;/'
```

`/exampledata:/!` makes the command execute on lines that don't contain `exampledata:`, and then it performs a more correct substitution.

Comment: does this need a 'g' at the end to make it loop globally/through every line even after having corrected one specific?

Comment: `g` is only needed for doing multiple replacements on a line.

Comment: `sed` loops through all lines by default.

Comment: oh ok i understand. i'll test your given example til tomorrow and report back. should work as wished i assume tho.